# Clojure take-while and n more items

Tags: clojure

What's the idiomatic way in Clojure to implement `take-while-and-n-more` below:

```
=> (take-while-and-n-more #(<= % 3)  1 (range 10))
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

My try is:

```
(defn take-while-and-n-more [pred n coll]
  (let
      [take-while-result (take-while pred coll)
       n0 (count take-while-result)] 
    (concat
     take-while-result
     (into [] (take n (drop n0 coll))))))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use [split-with](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/split-with), which is equivalent of getting results of both take-while and drop-while for the same parameters:

```
(defn take-while-and-n-more [pred n coll]
    (let [[head tail] (split-with pred coll)]
         (concat head (take n tail))))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
(defn take-while-and-n-more [pred n coll]
  (let [[a b] (split-with pred coll)]
    (concat a (take n b))))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is a modified version of Clojures `take-while`. Where Clojures `take-while` returns `nil` as a default case (when the predicate does not match), this one invokes `take` to take the the additional items after the predicate fails.

Note that unlike versions using `split-with`, this version traverses the sequence only once.

```
(defn take-while-and-n-more
  [pred n coll]
  (lazy-seq
   (when-let [s (seq coll)]
     (if (pred (first s))
       (cons (first s) (take-while-and-n-more pred n (rest s)))
       (take n s)))))
```

Comment: concat returns a lazy sequence

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer. Still, split-with will result in traversing the predicate-matching part of the sequence twice.